# Update user_email via php - WP 4.7

Tags: php, wpdb

I am brand new to php and web development. I've made a front-end edit profile page for users, and every field updates except email (but, everything else is user meta). I have spent way too long on this to no avail.

There are lots of posts about this, such as this one [How do you update user_email on the front end in WP 3.3?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45208/how-do-you-update-user-email-on-the-front-end-in-wp-3-3), but I cannot get any of the methods suggested to work for me. I am using WP 4.7.3.

This is from the above post. It DOES update the email, but my page hangs indefinitely after I submit my form:

```
wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $_POST['email'] ) );
```

I also tried this way. It does not update the user's email, and it doesn't hang:

```
$wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_email' => $_POST['email']), array('ID' => $current_user->ID));
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am pretty sure the issue lies just in this piece of code, but I can include more code if that helps.

Edited: update user profile code. Turns out password hangs indefinitely too.

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

/* Update user information. */

    // Email
    if (isset( $_POST['email'])) {
            // check if user is really updating the value
            if ($user_email != $_POST['email']) {           
                    // check if email is free to use
                    if (email_exists( $_POST['email'] )){
                        // Email exists, do not update value.
                        $error[] = __('This email is already in use.', 'profile');
                    } 
                    else if (!is_email( $_POST['email'] )){
                        // Not correct email format.
                        $error[] = __('Email is in incorrect format.', 'profile');
                    } 
                    else {
                        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $_POST['email'] ) );
                        //$wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_email' => $_POST['email']), array('ID' => $current_user->ID));
                 }   
         }
    }  

    // Password
if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
    else {
      $error[] = __('Passwords do not match.', 'profile');
            }
}

    // First name
if ( !empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) ){
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first-name'] ) );
    }

    // Last name
if ( !empty( $_POST['last-name'] ) )
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last-name'] ) );

    // Birth year
if ( !empty( $_POST['birth_year'] ) ) {
        // Make sure it's all numbers
        if (!ctype_digit($_POST['birth_year'])){
    $error[] = __('Please enter a year.', 'profile');
        }
        else
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'birth_year', esc_attr( $_POST['birth_year'] ) );
    }

    // Phone
if ( !empty( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'phone', esc_attr( $_POST['phone'] ) );
    }

    // Street address
if ( !empty( $_POST['address'] ) )
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'street_address', esc_attr( $_POST['address'] ) );

    // City
if ( !empty( $_POST['city'] ) )
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'city', esc_attr( $_POST['city'] ) );

    // State
if ( !empty( $_POST['state'] ) )
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'state', esc_attr( $_POST['state'] ) );

    // Parent's first name
if ( !empty( $_POST['p_first_name'] ) )
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'player_parent_first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['p_first_name'] ) );

    // Parent's last name
if ( !empty( $_POST['p_last_name'] ) )
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'player_parent_last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['p_last_name'] ) );

    // Parent's email
    if (isset( $_POST['p_email'])) {
        // check if user is really updating the value
        if ($user_email != $_POST['p_email']) {       
                if (!is_email( $_POST['p_email'] )){
                    // Not correct email format.
                    $error[] = __('Parent email is in incorrect format.', 'profile');
                } 
                else {
                    $args = array(
                        'ID' => $current_user->id,
                        'player_parent_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['p_email'] )
                );            
                wp_update_user( $args );
                }   
        }
    }

    // Parent's phone
    if ( !empty( $_POST['p_phone'] ) ) {
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'player_parent_phone', esc_attr( $_POST['p_phone'] ) );
    }

/* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
    // Make sure there are no errors
if ( count($error) == 0 ) {
            echo "redirecting";
    //action hook for plugins and extra fields saving
    do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
            wp_redirect( get_permalink().'?updated=true' );
    exit;
}   
    else {
        // print errors here
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you add a hook anywhere that fires during wp_update_user()?

Comment: No, I haven't  - what would that entail?

Comment: If you add an action or filter that fires during wp_update_user() and from that hook you call wp_update_user(), you'll create an infinite loop. Which is what it appears you are describing. Also, you need to sanitize the email before inserting into the database: sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] ). What you have now is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: That must be it. I tweaked someone else's code and see now there is one. I'm really sorry, I didn't even notice. I've added my code to my question. I'm a little confused - I assume that action is vital to the other fields?

Comment: Please ignore my minimal error checking and lack of error printing. I just want to get this sorted out now before I add more error-related code.

Comment: Eek. I guess I didn't need the do_action at all. If I remove that, it still hangs, but usermeta fields work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it might be something with my theme I'm not understanding. I'd much like to make the $wpdb->update function happen if anyone has any advice! I've messed with it for a while now and still doesn't work. No idea why.

Comment: Where do you have that code at?  Is it inside a function being called by an action or filter, or is it inside a theme file?  Depending on where it is, you probably don't need a redirect.

Comment: Interesting - the redirect is the only way I was able to load the updated fields immediately after the user submits (maybe I need to adjust some cache settings somewhere?). I have it in a theme page file (like page-edit-profile.php). Think it'd work if I moved it to functions.php or maybe made a plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using $wpdb->update:

```
$ID = $current_user->ID;
$email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
$wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_email' => $email), array('ID' => $ID));
```

Not exactly sure what the issue was with wp_update_user unfortunately.